# Catchable WP_Error

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am getting this error on my WordPress installation

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 390
```

I tried to disable all themes and plugins by renaming the plugins folder but I can't access the backend.

Please advice

UPDATE: I replaced all the files inside wp-admin and wp-includes and it brought me back to the original error I had, which points to rewrite.php instead of taxonomy.php (in other words, taxonomy.php was an error received as a result of changing something in wp-includes).

The real error is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/tsbiet/public_html/wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 280
```

Still looking for help on this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you somehow delete a custom taxonomy that is linked to a menu item.

Back up your database, go to the to wp_term_taxonomy table and query for all records with nav_menu in the taxonomy column and delete them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did that but the error remains.